# Can "proper" be used proper as an adverb?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, sentence

Which one is correct?

> - I hope I thanked you **proper**!
> - I hope I thanked you **properly**!

Comment: The second one. Also, [read this](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Though the flat adverb _proper_ is used in certain limited circumstances (They were beaten good and proper; Can't she talk proper?), it would sound like slang, dialect  or even be unacceptable here.

Comment: You will sometimes read something like "I hope I thanked you proper" when the speaker is presumably using a certain dialect (rural in the US, and I think also rural in England).  But "prescriptive" rules disallow "proper" as an adverb, and "descriptive" rules discourage it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [“He acted stange(ly?)”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32502/he-acted-strangely). That question is asking about an entirely different construction where _strange_ is in fact an adjective, not an adverb. This question is about flat adverbs; there is no way _proper_ in this question can be analysed as an adjective in the sense intended here. I’ve voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I thanked you properly.  Properly is an adverb, modifying the verb thanked.

Comment: Hello, Steve. Yes, but this is not a substantial enough answer for ELU. Why is 'proper' not acceptable here (and remember, it **is** sometimes used as an adverb)?

Answer (score 0):

In general, adverbs in English end *-ly,* and adjectives do not. There are irregular adverbs like *well,* and others like *hard* (which does not mean *hardly*).

Some may say that although *properly* exists as an adverb, *proper* may be an adverbial form too. I contend that it is not one in Standard English.

It can be used as an adverb in dialectal English (“Can’t she talk proper?” would not be out of place in south or east London) and it does exist in the fixed phrase *good and proper* (“I fixed it good and proper; it will never come apart!”) where that entire fixed phrase becomes an adverb.

In Standard English, the adverbial form of *proper* is ***properly.***

The [related question about strange/strangely](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32502/he-acted-strangely) is worth a read.