# "I sure am" or "I surely am"

Tags: verbs, adverbs

Imagine somebody asks to confirm your identity;

"Are you Mr./Ms. X?"

Do you reply with "I sure am!" or "I surely am!"?

I'm struggling to know whether to apply the adverb form here. What's the rule with adverbs and "to be"? Phrases like "I am cold" or "She is tired" seem all right, but ones like "I am good" seem more suspect.

Comment: To me (a British English speaker), 'I sure am' sounds like American colloquial speech. 'correct' English would be 'I surely (_or_ certainly) am'.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/32502/14666

Comment: @KateBunting To me, even "I surely am" is inappropriate. You'd make a definite statement, such as "I am". You don't need to deduce your name by interring anything; you know it, surely?

Comment: @RosieF As indicated, I meant 'surely' in the sense of 'certainly', not of expressing doubt. (_Surely_ you must mean _inferring_, not _interring_!)

Answer (score -1):

"I sure am" is more assertive. "I surely am" is like implying that "I almost certainly am, but there is a slight chance I am not." I would use it if I was in a word-playing mood.